# My Commodes are flushing and filling back up as normal but I don’t have any water coming in any of my sinks ( Kitchen and Bathroom)

Tags: plumbing

It started water running out of kitchen sink in a string, and bathroom 1 sink had little pressure but Bathroom 2 sink was just fine, then the next day I had no water coming out of either sink, but my commodes flushes as normal

Comment: Is this a frozen pipes problem?

Comment: What part of world are you in and is it Winter?

Comment: Have you checked the aerators?

Comment: What kind of water pipes do you have: copper? PEX? PVC or CPVC? PEX can freeze with no damage so when the pipes thaw the water flows again and you have no leaks. The others will often split and start leaking water then they thaw. Is your kitchen faucet on an outside wall? Bathroom lavatories on outside walls? Open the cabinet doors on all these and blow air in if you can. Of course remove any contents if young children or pets  could be harmed by consuming poisonous products.

Comment: Do you have a slab foundation? pier and beam with crawl space? basement? Where is this?

Answer (score 1):

A valve is closed or a pipe is blocked. Frozen pipe would be the scenario that would worry me most at this time of year in the northern hemisphere, since frozen pipes can burst and make things much worse. (Water expands when it freezes, unlike most materials.)

You need to find the last point where the pipes that work branch off from the pipes that don't, then figure out how that section differs from the others and how to fix it. The details depend on your house"s construction and which pipes are involved.